# Ethernet Not Detected Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, internet, ethernet, wired

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 and cannot get my ethernet to be detected. My ethernet works fine on other Windows 10 computers, but Ubuntu does not detect the connection.

Output of  `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3`:

```
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V [8086:15b8]
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V [1043:8672]
        Kernel modules: e1000e
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1b80]
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:85aa]
```

[image: output]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3` terminal command.